# Run jQuery code only the first time a user visits the website

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have this code

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#videoOverlay").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById("video").play();
}, 8000);
```

This means 8 seconds after loading, a pop-up will come up and a video will play. I only want this to come up the first time I visit the site. How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: You tagged your question with cookies, so have you tried to set and read a cookie?

Comment: No window will pop up and no video will be played. The default is to have javascript disabled and popups blocked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/

Comment: @Brandon I agree, but this is a website for a musician, so it's not advertising per-say, it's content that the user of the site would be looking for.

Comment: @SebastianAlsina - wrong what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with **[localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)** instead of cookie:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('viewed')){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#videoOverlay").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById("video").play();
        localStorage.setItem('viewed','yes');
    }, 8000);
};
```

To delete it:

```
localStorage.removeItem('viewed');
```

With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.

> FROM http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**What is HTML Local Storage?**

Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included in every server request. Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

> Using: **sessionStorage**

You can also use **sessionStorage** object that is equal to the **localStorage** object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab.

```
if (!sessionStorage.viewed){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#videoOverlay").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById("video").play();
        sessionStorage.viewed=1
    }, 8000);
};
```

Comment: This worked like charm. Could you explain to me the difference between localStorage and cookies? To my understanding, this should be done with cookies, but localStorage successfully did it, and it seems like they both act the same. Would you be kind enough to enlighten me on the difference?

Comment: Of course! I've added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Also remember that if you need to remove it **localStorage.removeItem('viewed');**

Comment: Usage of localStorage is perfect example for my use case.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you could try this jquery cookie plugin
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

and then you can use it with

```
Cookies.get('name'); 
Cookies.set('name','value');
```

Comment: Thanks! Another user suggested I use localStorage and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: I admit I didn't use either of these libraries but it looks like your code is for the old, deprecated https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie. The new library you're linking to doesn't seem to be a jQuery plugin any more and has a different syntax. Also, in the code didn't you accidentally swap writing of the cookie with reading?

Comment: @kamilk you are correct. I had that code for the old plugin and did not realize i linked a newer version. I changed the answer.
As far as i know writing to the cookie we can do every time (if it already exists it will be overwriten or am i wrong?)