# jQuery meta refresh redirect page only once

Tags: jquery, redirect, cookies, refresh

I need to redirect users to a different page after 12 seconds,but only one time. By means if they back to the previous page they will not be redirected. I am trying to use cookies in this like this :

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function(){

    if($.cookie('Visited') != 'yes'){

    $.cookie('Visited', 'yes', { path: '/', expires: 1 });

     window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";

     }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: you can check this awnsers. I hope it's you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397732/run-jquery-code-only-the-first-time-a-user-visits-the-website

Comment: thank you,but localStore works only with html5 I guess?

Comment: window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
    window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)   both can not help me coz I need to redirect to another page once for a specific time set in cookies expiration one day for example